# CFWheels 'request.wheels.execution' struct dump issues

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I am running a cfwheels application on Coldfusion 9 and I need to get the native debug variables of cfhweels to store them in a db table.

I am trying to get `#request.wheels.execution#` which returns a struct with running times of the controller, action, request. When I dump the struct I am getting a few million milliseconds as running times and the exact same code at the bottom of my screen shows a couple of hundred milliseconds which is the correct times.

Anyone know how these numbers are translated to the numbers showing on the debug section?

This is the code that I got straight from cfwheels that outputs the running times on the bottom of my screen but when I isolate the code the numbers get all messed up again.

```
 <cfif request.wheels.execution.total GT 0>
    (<cfset loc.keys = StructSort(request.wheels.execution, "numeric", "desc")>
     <cfset loc.firstDone = false>

        <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(loc.keys)#" index="loc.i">
            <cfset loc.key =    loc.keys[loc.i]>
            <cfif loc.key IS NOT "total" AND request.wheels.execution[loc.key] GT 0>
                <cfif loc.firstDone>
                    , 
                </cfif>
                    #LCase(loc.key)# ~#request.wheels.execution[loc.key]#ms<cfset loc.firstDone = true>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>)
    </cfif>
```

Answer (score 0):

The values you're seeing in the debug output are the differences in milliseconds recorded by the framework as it calls `getTickCount()` at different times during the request.

You can demo this by reloading in design mode and adding this to the top of your layout view:

```
<cfset ticks = getTickCount() />
```

Then, as the last line in the view, add this:

```
<cfoutput>
this view took #getTickCount()-ticks# milliseconds to process.
</cfoutput>
```